# Trying to parse JSON files using Scrapy

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to parse files much like [this](http://proadvisorservice.intuit.com/v1/search?latitude=39&longitude=-91&radius=100&pageNumber=1&pageSize=&sortBy=distance) one, but for a lot of longitudes and latitudes. The crawler loops through all of the webpages, but doesn't output anything.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
import json

from tutorial.items import DmozItem
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["proadvisorservice.intuit.com"]

    min_lat = 35
    max_lat = 40
    min_long = -100
    max_long = -90

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(self.min_lat, self.max_lat):
            for j in range(self.min_long, self.max_long):
                yield scrapy.Request('http://proadvisorservice.intuit.com/v1/search?latitude=%d&longitude=%d&radius=100&pageNumber=1&pageSize=&sortBy=distance' % (i, j), 
                    meta={'index':(i, j)},
                    callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())

        for x in jsonresponse['searchResults']:
            item = DmozItem()

            item['firstName'] = x['firstName']
            item['lastName'] = x['lastName']
            item['phoneNumber'] = x['phoneNumber']
            item['email'] = x['email']
            item['companyName'] = x['companyName']
            item['qbo'] = x['qbopapCertVersions']
            item['qbd'] = x['papCertVersions']

            yield item
```

Comment: The is no `print()` in your code.

Comment: I'm calling it through terminal..."scrapy crawl dmoz -o items.json"...why would I need print?...it should output all items into the file items.json

Comment: To solve this sort of problem you put a lot of `print()` statements into your code to bisect where is information is lost. Without that you don't know if maybe `scrapy.Request()` stalls, if you mistakenly swapped the start and end of the range, if `response.body_as_unicode()` stalls or what ever the problem is. First find the point that is not reached, then comment again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `CrawlSpider` you should **not** override the `parse()` method:

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since
>   the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.
>   ([source](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.Rule))

But since you are customizing your spider manually, and not using the `CrawlSpider` functionality anyway, I would suggest that you don't inherit from it. Instead, inherit from `scrapy.Spider`:

```
class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    ...
```

Comment: When I take off the CrawlSpider inheritance I get an error: 

raise NotImplementedError
exceptions.NotImplementedError:

Comment: And when I change parse into say parse_site (or anything else) I get the error: exceptions.AttributeError: 'DmozSpider' object has no attribute 'parse_site'

Comment: You need to change the function also: `def parse()` to `def parse_site()`. And for the NotImplementedError, I need to see the stack trace.